# duplicate eclipse

Tags: eclipse, configuration, duplicates, setting

I have eclipse Indigo version and i can run both java and C++ projects in it.
But i want to use another eclipse only to write C++ projects . so I copied(not cutted) the source folder of eclipse(not workspace) into different location. I was expecting that eclipse will ask for workplace location and there will be no projects in project explorer , but there was my old prjects and didnt ask for workspace location. I dont know how to make a new eclipse while I dont want to delete or damage the old one.
btw I dont have a fast internet connection to download eclipse again.
if u know how to fix my problem please help me.

Comment: why not just use separate workspaces?

Answer (score 2):

How about you create a new workspace (either by selecting *File* > *Switch Workspace* or by restarting Eclipse).

As soon as Eclipse is running from the new workspace, you can import the project you want. You can do this by right clicking in the the Package Explorer View and selecting *Import*. Then select the *General* tab and within that select the *Existing Projects into Workspace*.

From here, you can navigate to your existing project and select it. If you want to edit this independently of the other workspace, you should also be able to specify that you want it to create a separate copy of this project on disk.

(Another option after creating the new workspace would be to simply copy the project folder from the old workspace into your new workspace.)

Comment: I know I can switch my workspace or import projects but the question is can I have 2 different workspaces in one eclipse , or 2 different workspaces for 2 different eclipses?

Comment: You can definitely do both of those things. I have 3 different Eclipse distributions and each has 3-5 different workspaces (for classes, research, personal projects, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

As detailed in Treebranch's answer, you could just have a single Eclipse installation with different workspaces.

However the reason you are not being prompted to choose a new workspace in the duplicated Eclipse folder is due to the the recent workspaces list also being copied - it is stored in the following file (in Eclipse 3.6 anyway):

```
\Eclipse\configuration\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs
```

If you open this with Notepad, you may see the flag `SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG` set to `false` (thus not showing the dialog on Eclipse startup). If you set it to `true`, Eclipse will prompt the next time it starts

Alternatively, this file can be safely deleted and Eclipse will re-create it on startup too